# OneDrive for business data retention post license deactivation

Tags: sharepoint, office365, onedrive-for-business

OneDrive for business data retention post license deactivation
My client doesn't want his users to use OneDrive for business.

They want to use Sharepoint on-premise. Unfortunately few of the users have enabled Onedrive as it was a part of Microsoft 365 Apps for Enterprise (formerly pro-plus) license bundle/pack.

As part of the remediation.

1. The Officeonline and Onedriveforbusiness services have been disabled in the M365 license option and reassigned to the users.
2. The existing personal sites lockstate is set to no access.

Q: **Some of the users had data in the onedrive sites. How long the data will be retained ? Will OD4B data deletion get triggered in this case ?**

Answer (score 0):

As of October 2020, the data will be retained forever unless you delete the user or stop syncing them.

[Source:](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/manage/remove-licenses-from-users?view=o365-worldwide#what-happens-to-a-users-data-when-you-remove-their-license) Files saved in OneDrive for Business aren't deleted unless the user is deleted from the Microsoft 365 admin center or is removed through Active Directory synchronization. For more information, see [OneDrive retention and deletion](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/retention-and-deletion). Based on your description of the scenario, the answer is no, data will not be deleted. As a best practice, the Client should configure Retention Policies in their Tenant for all 365 services.